# Symfony 3.2 secure clear DB password

Tags: database, symfony, ovh

I know the security 0 don't exist and I don't would like a person can access into my server and see the DB password in clear!

I try to figure out how to protect my clear password for the DB in Symfony 3.2.
I got some information [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html).
But I have an OVH server and impossible to configure the server and I know it's possible to do it by .htaccess. I just want to do that correctly without mistakes!

Comment: Uh, ... have you tried with ovh help desk?

Comment: You have password of your users or (or you) stored as plain text in a database ?

Comment: @COil no, in the setting on your symfony app, you have to put the parameters about your database (user,pass,port,password,...). I don't want to put in plain text there.